# Significance of Asymptotic Time complexity while Programming/Coding?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, code-generation

I have heard a lot about time complexity.Time complexity itself is an Aproximation,since we are concerned about Worstcase(Big-Oh),Bestcase(Big-Omega) and Average(Theta).

Each programming language includes lots of built-in-functions.I really dont know if there is a way to check th time complexity of these functions.
Since we are using buit-in-functions,

> Do we really need to Consider the `Time complexity while coding`?
>   What about the space complexity?
>
> Is there any way to check the time complexity of these functions.
>   Since we are using buit-in-functions?

Comment: Depending on the language, it's possible to find reference docs that tell you the complexity (C++ for example). It's reasonable, IMHO, to assume they are meeting the accepted complexities found in any good algorithm book. If not and you have access to the source, then you can do it the hard way and calculate it up.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Generally you're right, though I'm aware of one common exception: searching for a given string inside another string can be done in linear time and constant space, but the standard libraries in many languages still implement the naive quadratic-time algorithm.  Admittedly this much simpler algorithm will probably be much faster for reasonably short strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do we really need to Consider the Time complexity while coding?

If your application *needs* to be able to scale up to larger problems, then yes.  Otherwise no.

> What about the space complexity?

Same answer.

> Is there any way to check the time complexity of these functions. Since we are using built-in-functions?

1. Read the documentation.  The complexity of methods for standard classes is often documented.
2. Use your knowledge of algorithmics.  For example, you should have been taught in your algorithmic unit in your CS course that sorting is `O(NlogN)` for decent sort algorithms, or that finding an element in a list is `O(N)` on average.  (If you didn't take an algorithmics uint, there are lots of good textbooks ...)
3. Inspect, and if necessary analyze, the source code of the builtin functions.

(Note: I do not recommend the "empirical" approach of estimating complexity. It can give you the wrong answer ... even ignoring the standard issues with measurement methodology.)

Comment: What about the time complexity for the buit-in functions

Comment: If you are analyzing code complexity, and built-in functions are used by the code, then you should consider them too.  Obviously.  If you don't consider them, then your complexity analysis could be incorrect.

Comment: Mypoint is Everyone likes use Built-in function for a specific task,since it is cook book and best algorithm available.Considering the less probability of writing a better code over built-in, if buit-in-plays a major cost in time-complexity. Then timecomplexity of our code will become insingnificant.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode Not really. If you write a piece of code that does some calculation within 3 nested loops, then it doesn't matter if a built-in Arrays.sort that you are calling outside the loops has O(nlogn) or O(n2) time complexity.

Comment: Subin - That thinking is incorrect.  For example, sort is `O(NlogN)`, irrespective of who implemented it.  If you call a builtin sort function in an `O(N)` loop your code will be `O(N^2logN)`.  If you "don't consider" the complexity of the sort (because it is builtin) you will mistakenly think that your code is `O(N)` or something.  In short, your analysis will give meaningless results.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check the time complexity of these functions. Since we are using built-in-functions?

Yes.
The most common way is to run it in a loop (10,000 - 10,000,000 times, depending on the function, software, precision of timers etc.) with timers (timestamp before and after, stopwatch, etc.) and then compare it to your other options.

**EDIT:**
You need to use many different input sizes, and note the potentially confusing effect of caching on measurements.

Comment: I'll +1 if you say explicitly that you need to use many different input sizes, and mention the potentially confusing effect of caching on measurements.

Comment: This is hard. For example consider the Simplex Algorithm, which takes exponential time in the worst case, but you're extremely unlikely to find those cases by generating them randomly.